# How could I map Alt on linux

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I am trying to  map the key Alt+j in vimrc to adjust the height of the window: 

`tnoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-n>5<C-w>-i
nnoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-n>5<C-w>-`

But it seems not to work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I add these lines in my vimrc, and the map for tnoremap works well but that for nnoremap does not work

Comment: I'm closing the question as a duplicate because so far the problem seems to be exactly the same as the other question. Please add more details, the relevant lines of your vimrc, what you tried, how you test your mappings and what you mean by "it does not work" so we can reopen the question.